# How to set Request instance defaults proxy as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a sync function to choose my proxy and I want to set default proxy to use function for instance of Request, like this:

```
const Request = require('request');

const reloadProxy = () => {
    let res = proxies.shift();
    proxies.push(res);
    return `http://${res.username}:${res.password}@${res.ip}:${res.port}`;
}

const request = Request.defaults({ proxy: reloadProxy });
```

but there is an Error:

```
Error: Invalid protocol: undefined
```

when I just try to

```
request.get('https://google.com');
```

So, how to solve this?

Comment: `Request.defaults({ proxy: getProxy() })` - did you forget to call the function?

Comment: No, I mean if I want this instance of Request static proxy its okey, but I want to use several times and all times to call this function.